# Notification send intent to broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to send an action to broadcast receiver from the notification ... I have made lots of research to find a way to fix it.. but I don't get the action on the broadcast receiver please help me a bit and sorry for any inconvenience i made .. !.

NOTIFICATION CODE:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidPlayer.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent("ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_PLAY");
        PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent stopIntent = new Intent("ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_STOP");
        PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Press to return.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_radio_white)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white, "Play", playPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_white, "Stop", stopPendingIntent)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

        if (this.isFinishing())
            notificationManager.cancel(0);

        super.onPause();
    }
```

BROADCAST RECEIVER:

```
package ovh.smonitor.androidplayer;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_PLAY")) {
            System.out.println("ACTION PLAY !.");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_STOP")) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MANIFEST ( INSIDE APPLICATION ):

```
<receiver
            android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_PLAY" />
                <action android:name="ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_STOP" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Why I don't get any answer on my receiver .?

Answer (score 0):

You add two actions to an IntentFilter tag,that means only two actions are sent at the same time,your receiver can receive the action and invoke `OnReceive`,So to fix it,just like this:
Replace

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_PLAY" />
     <action android:name="ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_STOP" />
 </intent-filter>
```

with

```
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_PLAY" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="ovh.smonitor.androidplayer.ACTION_STOP" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: thnx for your time.. already find the way to get the intents from broadcast.. my problem is .. that i cant use the mediaplayer object already played on the main activity.. so i can stop it and replay it from notification .. i get error that media player is null ... so i cant stop it with notification bar only with main activity app .. can you help me with this ?

Comment: I think you can use **dynamic receiver** instead of **static receiver**:create your receiver in your main activity,then you can get the mediaplayer object when received some actions.And since your last problem has been solved,you's better update your question to let others know your current problem.